# Allow drag/drop of specific file type in Eclipse SWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, drag-and-drop, swt

I need to support file-drop into my Eclipse RCP application.

I've got file-drop support working, by defining the target UI element as a DropTarget.  But, I only wish to allow users to drop in files of a particular file type (by suffix).

With FileTransfer type objects, the filename is contained in the event.data field, but this field is only populated in the drop() event, not in DragEnter or DragOver.  I'd really like to give a visual feedback on unacceptable type during the drag, not after the item has been dropped.

Can anybody offer any pointers?

(I was investigating an extension of FileTransfer, but that has a protected constructor.)

cheers,
Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is platform specific. E.g event.dataTypes[].data contains required information on Windows.
Check [SWT Examples: determine data types available](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet83.java) as a starting point.

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Is it really platform specific?  If I've got a FileTransfer object I'm sure it will have a filename (it's a list of Strings).  My challenge is accessing the filename in a method other than drop().

Comment: What I mean is that you COULD access filename in dragEnter, but only on win32 and probably motif.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Max.  Inevitably, I'm developing on OSX.  As with any Java/Eclipse question, I should have made the platform clear.  thanks again, Ian.